How do I change the SharePoint Start Page?
I'm setting up a SharePoint tenant; we have multiple sites, and essentially each one relates to a department of the company.  We're using modern SharePoint online.
When we go to the SharePoint Start Page, we see the standard lists of "News from Sites" and then "Favourite Sites".  However, we'd really like to change this so that it's more in tune with the individual sites.  How do we do this?
I'm happy to write Web Parts, but we can't see any way to add them.  At the moment it seems as though our options are:

Create a landing page and then tell SharePoint to use it as the Home Page - we tried this but couldn't figure out how to tell SharePoint to use it.

Viva Connections - we were able to set up a connection experience, but then couldn't get any further.  We set up a communications site, and then tried to post its URL into the URL box that popped up, but again, SharePoint didn't seem to pick up on it to use it.


Apart from this we've been able to customize SharePoint really well, but the start page looks terrible, and we really need to change it otherwise people won't use it and we might as well go back to the old system we had.
Can anyone tell me what the options are here, and how to implement them?
